# 404 Not Found nginx/1.22.0 after upgrading my website to PHP 8 in Azure

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, nginx

I am trying to upgrade my website from PHP 7.4 to 8.0 in Azure. What I did was to create a blank website on PHP 8 and then used a site migrating tool like "All-in-One WP Migration Unlimited Extension" to download the site from source and upload it to the destination. Once the upload is complete, it gives a "404 Not Found nginx/1.22.0" error and the site won't come up.

I understand the problem lies in the docker container while moving from Linux (source) to Nginx (target). Since I'm a Windows guy, I don't know what I need to be doing to make my application work on the target environment.

If someone can give me step by step instructions on what file to be edited and what needs to be added, please post it here. I know how to use Vi editor by the way. If you are going to point me to an article, please make sure that the article is an up-to-date one because I followed this article - https://azureossd.github.io/2021/09/02/php-8-rewrite-rule/index.html and it didn't work.